# Create groups of arrays into one array using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have one lab where is given:
`const names = ['Peter', 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Mark', 'Josh', 'Sandra', 'Cris', 'Bernard', 'Takesi'];`

It's required to create function that will create array which will contain other arrays with three names:

```
`[['Peter', 'Andrew', 'Ann'], ['Mark', 'Josh', 'Sandra'], ['Cris', 'Bernard', 'Takesi']]`
```

I did below and it gives me one array , as expected:

```
function sortByGroups() {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i = i + 3){
        for (let j = i; j < i + 3; j++){
            if (j < i + 2){
                arr += `${names[j]},`;
            } else {
                arr += `${names[j]}`;
            }
        }
        return arr.split(',')
    }
}
console.log(sortByGroups()); // [ 'Peter', 'Andrew', 'Ann' ]
```

but after I don't know what to do to get the required result:
`[['Peter', 'Andrew', 'Ann'], ['Mark', 'Josh', 'Sandra'], ['Cris', 'Bernard', 'Takesi']]`

Comment: For the inner loop, you need to create a 2nd array, fill it with 3 names, then push that into the outer array.

Comment: Also, don't `return` until _after_ the outer loop.

Comment: Concatenating strings to an array is *really* not what you want to do. Hint: `push()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 1):

#### From a list of integers i=0,1,2, you can get elements 3*i to 3*i+2

A for-loop based version might be this:

```js
const names = ['Peter', 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Mark', 'Josh', 'Sandra', 'Cris', 'Bernard', 'Takesi'];

const groupedNames = []
for(let j=0; j<Math.ceil(names.length); j+=3){
groupedNames.push(names.slice(j,j+3))
}
console.log(groupedNames)
```

#### A fully functional approach is here

It creates the list of integers first, and then maps the entries into it.

```js
const names = ['Peter', 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Mark', 'Josh', 'Sandra', 'Cris', 'Bernard', 'Takesi'];

const groupedNames = Array(Math.ceil(names.length/3)).fill(0).map((_,i)=>names.slice(3*i,3*(i+1)))

console.log(groupedNames)
```

Comment: Cool! Your solution is advanced and I will take it to use it in the future. @Nikkkshit's solution is more suitable for my level of knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- We are looping through, all names, using temporary variable `lastUsedIndex` to store value of last element inserted in last group, and just making sure next time that current index should be greater than `lastUserIndex`.
- One thing to note, if there will be another extra element in source data then it will add group like `['that data',undefined,undefined]`.

```js
const names = ['Peter', 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Mark', 'Josh', 'Sandra', 'Cris', 'Bernard', 'Takesi'];
let lastUsedIndex = -1;
const groupedNames = [];
names.forEach((name, i) => {
  if (i > lastUsedIndex) {
    lastUsedIndex = i + 2;
    groupedNames.push([names[i], names[i + 1], names[i + 2]]);
  }
})

console.log(groupedNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` to iterate the return the resulting array.

```js
const names = ['Peter', 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Mark', 'Josh', 'Sandra', 'Cris', 'Bernard', 'Takesi'];

const createGroups = (size) => names.reduce((prev, curr, ix) => {
    let arrIx = Math.floor(ix / size);
    prev[arrIx] = [...(prev[arrIx] || []), curr];
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(createGroups(3));
```